# Is it possible simultaneously redirect and send and AJAX request without waiting for the AJAX request's response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to collect stats on a hyperlink but redirect without waiting for possibly slow AJAX response. Is it possible simultaneously redirect and send and AJAX request without waiting for the AJAX request's response? As it is I have a `window.location.replace()` after a `$.post()`, sometimes the AJAX call is made and sometimes not.

Comment: Can you post the code? It should run if it's before the url change. You shouldn't have to wait for the response for anything to happen.

Comment: @Leeish There is no guarantee of that.

Comment: I was thinking to put in a short Timeout or page change on `ajaxStart`. If you redirect after it starts then you should be good. Like you said though, without waiting for the response, you're opening yourself up for failure.

Comment: Not sure what platform you are working with, but we did this with WCF. We return a response 200 immediately and the client just moves on, and we put the actual work in a queue (MSMQ in this case, but I guess there are other solutions or you can even roll your own).

Comment: @Leeish That's incorrect... a short timeout (or even a longer timeout!) offers no guarantee that the request will start.  You must wait for the response.  Don't forget about slower devices.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so, if you are manually clicking on a link just after you make an ajax request and are waiting for its response.. Firefox wont show any alert but it wont allow click, Chrome does show an alert.

In case you are using javascript to redirect using window.location.href after you make ajax request, it might do redirection without waiting for response of the ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is, but if you don't wait for the response, how do you know the request fully finished?

As you have already seen, a fire-and-forget-and-immediately-redirect tears down all objects and requests currently running for the current page context.  Since the browser doesn't expose any underlying TCP hooks to know that the data was sent, if you need to make sure the request actually sent, you need to wait for a response from the server.

Comment: Downvote with no explanation?  Why?  This is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Not sure who did that, but again, what about redirecting on ajaxstart? Would that guarantee the request was sent?

Comment: @leeish That event is fired when the request begins, but there is no guarantee that the request is finished.

Comment: I'm confused... request begins = request sent? You are saying no? He's only worried about the request being sent.

Comment: @Leeish No, the beginning of a request does not mean the request was sent.  It means the request has begun.  It isn't something that happens instantaneously.  I know what he's asking for, and I'm telling you that it isn't possible, and have explained as to why.

Comment: Well that's too bad. I like Elad's solution above if you control the receiving end of the request, though it takes some work to implement.

Comment: @Leeish Elad's solution is exactly what I'm saying you must do!  You must return a response from the server, and it takes almost no work to implement... assuming you have control over what you are connecting to.